# Invalid location: latitude must be a number

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, geofirestore

I'm trying to perform a GeoQuery with [geofirestore](https://www.npmjs.com/package/geofirestore). I'd like to grab all documents in a given collection which are within a radius of 1000.

Here is my .js file:

```
const GeoFirestore = require('geofirestore').GeoFirestore;
const GeoPoint = require('geopoint');
const firebase = require('firebase');

firebase.initializeApp({
    projectId : 'my-project-id'
});

module.exports = {
   getLocalDocuments: getLocalDocuments
}

async function getLocalDocuments() {
    let latitude = 38.9537323;
    let longitude = -77.3507578;
    let radius = 1000;

    // Create a Firestore reference
    const firestore = firebase.firestore();

    // Create a GeoFirestore reference
    const geofirestore = new GeoFirestore(firestore);

    // Create a GeoCollection reference
    const geocollection = geofirestore.collection('myDocs');

    const query = geocollection.near({
        center: new GeoPoint(latitude, longitude),
        radius
    });

    // Get query (as Promise)

    await query.get().then((value) => {
        console.log(`value.docs: ${value.docs}`); // All docs returned by GeoQuery
    });
}
```

I'm getting the following stack trace when the *getLocalDocuments()* function is called:

```
Error: Invalid location: latitude must be a number
    at validateLocation (/srv/node_modules/geofirestore/dist/index.cjs.js:567:15)
    at validateQueryCriteria (/srv/node_modules/geofirestore/dist/index.cjs.js:600:9)
    at GeoCollectionReference.GeoQuery.near (/srv/node_modules/geofirestore/dist/index.cjs.js:1416:9)
    at getLocalDocuments (/srv/utils/locationService.js:45:33)
    at Object.getLocalDocuments (/srv/utils/locationService.js:58:11)
    at buildLocalTPRecipients (/srv/utils/notificationInstructorGenerator.js:370:43)
    at notifyTPOfLocalJobsInstructionGenerator (/srv/utils/notificationInstructorGenerator.js:255:32)
    at Object.generateNewJobInstructions (/srv/utils/notificationInstructorGenerator.js:98:29)
    at handleOnCreate (/srv/db/jobs/onCreate.f.js:20:53)
    at cloudFunction (/srv/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:131:23)
```

Here is the *validateLocation* method:

```
function validateLocation(location, flag) {
    if (flag === void 0) { flag = false; }
    var error;
    if (!location) {
        error = 'GeoPoint must exist';
    }
    else if (typeof location.latitude === 'undefined') {
        error = 'latitude must exist on GeoPoint';
    }
    else if (typeof location.longitude === 'undefined') {
        error = 'longitude must exist on GeoPoint';
    }
    else {
        var latitude = location.latitude;
        var longitude = location.longitude;
        if (typeof latitude !== 'number' || isNaN(latitude)) {
            error = 'latitude must be a number';
        }
        else if (latitude < -90 || latitude > 90) {
            error = 'latitude must be within the range [-90, 90]';
        }
        else if (typeof longitude !== 'number' || isNaN(longitude)) {
            error = 'longitude must be a number';
        }
        else if (longitude < -180 || longitude > 180) {
            error = 'longitude must be within the range [-180, 180]';
        }
    }
    if (typeof error !== 'undefined' && !flag) {
        throw new Error('Invalid location: ' + error);
    }
    else {
        return !error;
    }
}
```

Any idea why it's saying that latitude is not a number? I've checked with isNaN() and other methods and they all say that is a number.

Comment: What does `console.log(typeof location.latitude);` say? (or longitude)

Comment: *Here is the validateLocation method* - you'll need to show how/where it's being called

Comment: @mwilson I can't add that statement to the *validateLocation* method since it's part of the node-modules package. I'm ignoring this folder when deploying the cloud function.

Comment: @JaromandaX It's getting passed the **center** property of the object passed inside of the geocollection.near({...}) call. Hope this helps.

Comment: What values are `location.latitude` and `location.longitude` holding? You may need to add some console.log statements to debug because something seems a bit off. As for [GeoPoint](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/GeoPoint), you can use `getLatitude()` and `getLongitude()` to retrieve the values for a certain GeoPoint object. Remember that `GeoPoint(double latitude, double longitude)` is a tuple.

Comment: @sllopis That's thing. I can't find out the values since the *validateLocation* function is being called by the geofirestore module and there's no way to add a console.log() to this function. Once the GeoPoint is created, it's passed to the geocollection.near({...}) mentioned above.

Comment: I noticed that you have a `radius` variable inside your `geocollection.near`, and as shown in this [example](https://geofirestore.com/#documentation) , you may need to use it in the way `radius: yourRadiusVariable`, which would be the same as `radius: 1000`. Can you go ahead and modify that and see whether this changes anything?

Comment: @sllopis Nothing changes since it's after the use of *center*.

Comment: Hi @MattRuiz, I am posting an answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi @MattRuiz, Were you able to fix this issue? I am getting "latitude must exist on geopoint" error. Thank you!

Comment: Hola @RLShyam, I was not. I ended up going with a zipcode-based solution instead which satisfied the requirement. I did not try MichaelSolati's approach.

Comment: @Matt Ruiz hi, thanks for getting back to me. I was able to fix the error I was getting. It’s because in some documents the geolocation object was not stored in the right format. I think the error you are seeing is also because of the same reason.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is located inside the `validateLocation` function on the following lines of code:

```
var latitude = location.latitude;
var longitude = location.longitude;
```

Instead, these lines should be:

```
var latitude = location.latitude();
var longitude = location.longitude();
```

Since `latitude` and `longitude` are getter methods.

---

As mentioned on [GeoPoint GitHub](https://github.com/davidwood/node-geopoint#methods)

`.latitude(inRadians)`: Return the point's latitude. By default, the latitude is in degrees, unless inRadians is true

`.longitude(inRadians)`: Return the point's longitude. By default, the longitude is in degrees, unless inRadians is true

---

### Repro steps

**Create** a certain `GeoPoint`:

```
var GeoPoint = require('geopoint'),
statueOfLiberty = new GeoPoint(40.689604, -74.04455);
```

and then, `console.log(statueOfLiberty)`, this is the expected **output** :

```
GeoPoint {
  _degLat: 40.689604,
  _degLon: -74.04455,
  _radLat: 0.7101675611326549,
  _radLon: -1.2923211906575673 
}
```

After this, to **validate** the above `GeoPoint`, I used the `validateLocation(location, flag)` function, which is the same one that you **used** and can also be **found** [here](https://github.com/geofirestore/geofirestore-js/blob/master/src/utils.ts):

```
function validateLocation(location, flag){

    if (flag === void 0) { flag = false; }
    var error;
    if (!location) {
        error = 'GeoPoint must exist';
    }
    else if (typeof location.latitude === 'undefined') {
        error = 'latitude must exist on GeoPoint';
    }
    else if (typeof location.longitude === 'undefined') {
        error = 'longitude must exist on GeoPoint';
    }
    else {
        var latitude = location.latitude;
        var longitude = location.longitude;
        if (typeof latitude !== 'number' || isNaN(latitude)) {
            error = 'latitude must be a number';
        }
        else if (latitude < -90 || latitude > 90) {
            error = 'latitude must be within the range [-90, 90]';
        }
        else if (typeof longitude !== 'number' || isNaN(longitude)) {
            error = 'longitude must be a number';
        }
        else if (longitude < -180 || longitude > 180) {
            error = 'longitude must be within the range [-180, 180]';
        }
    }
    if (typeof error !== 'undefined' && !flag) {
        throw new Error('Invalid location: ' + error);
    }
    else {
        return !error;
    }
}
```

**Call** the function in your code like this:

`validateLocation(statueOfLiberty);`

---

The results are no different than the **error message** that you received.

The whole story changes when you use the **proper getter method calling** inside the `validateLocation` function as mentioned above:

```
var latitude = location.latitude();
var longitude = location.longitude();
```

Answer (score 0):

so, you don't/aren't supposed to use the library called "geopoint." Geopoints are a firebase/firestore object...

```
const firebase = require('firebase');
const GeoPoint = firebase.firestore.GeoPoint;
```

Make that change and everything else should work.